# Finding value of unknown modulo.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the following problem:

```
ID % NUM = KEY
```

Where `ID` and `KEY` are both given, but `KEY` is in base 64. How do I go about solving for the value of `NUM`? I can add any details possibly required for this. Thank you.

Given problem:

```
707406075829420062 % NUM = c0NzY1MDIzMDZ9
```

(Also, apologies for the tags, I wasn't allowed to add the algebra or modulo tags as they don't exist yet. I was unsure of what else would possibly fit this.)

Comment: What contest is it? Is contest over--(what date)?

Comment: @coffeemath that is why I gave an apology at the end, this really has nothing to do with any competition, but due to the fact that I couldn't add the modulo or algebra tags to it, I wasn't sure what else might fit. It is a challenge I was presented with among many others, but it's not a sanctioned official contest.

Comment: Usually when one writes $a\%b=c$ one means that $c$ is the remainder on dividing $a$ by $b$.  Thus, $c≤a$ for example,  Is that the case here?  I don't know how to read base $64$ but that number certainly looks huge.

Comment: Do you know what values the digits on right side have? Some are capital some small letters...

Comment: There can be potentially many choices for `NUM`.  Rewording, you ask if we can find $b$ given that $a\%b=c$ using comp-sci meaning of `%` as an operator.  This would occur when $a-c$ is a multiple of $b$ and $0\leq c<b$.  Look at the factors of $a-c$ and see which are greater than $c$.

Comment: For instance, $105\%b=5$ for each $b$ among $10,20,25,50,$ and $100$, noting that the factors of $105-5=100$ are precisely $1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100$

Comment: The theory is the same here for your original problem too, just muddled by the fact that the numbers are (*all?*) written in base 64 rather than base 10 like we are more comfortable with and the numbers are huge.  It may be infeasible to find the list of factors for `ID - KEY` if the numbers are too large (*RSA encryption is secure thanks to such large numbers*), but you'll have to factor it if you want the list of what all `NUM` could be and any other approach (*if it were to generate the same full list*) would effectively be equivalent since it generates the same information.

Comment: @JMoravitz I should have stated at first that the number ID is in b10, but the number KEY is b64. My issue is that KEY is much larger than ID, and when subtracted, results in a negative number. I'm honestly not sure how but I know it probably does affect it. And yeah, KEY is more than 10^24 lol

Comment: Then depending on what data types they are you either get that there is no solution or you get some sort of underflow happening.

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, I have a python script working to find the factors of the absolute difference between KEY and ID, will that be helpful? Also, since that number is huge, it's taking a long time, I don't know that I'll have an answer in even an hour lol.

Comment: Again, factoring a large number is in many cases infeasible and it is precisely thanks to that that RSA encryption works.  If people could factor numbers used for encryption in a matter of days or weeks on a home computer then online transactions wouldn't be safe.

Comment: Well, thanks for letting me know, I'll look for another method or I'll let someone better find the answer. Thank you all for the help! @JMoravitz

Comment: The main point of this exercise is probably that it can be solved in principle and not how efficient this is in practice. And to be infeasible to be factored , depending what we consider to be "not feasible" , the number must be very large and have a large second-largest prime factor.